# Is there a direct way to convert Map<String, List<String>> into a JSON String (using javax.json library)

Tags: java, json, java-8

Lets assume I have the following Map

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("First in list");
list.add("Second in list");

map.put("First in map", list);
```

So how can I convert it in a direct way to a JSON String using **javax.json** library?

Comment: It should be javax.json for some reason? or could be other?

Comment: yes, i just want to use JDK java library not other external libs, i know many ways to convert it direct using Gson lib or using jackson lib, but i just want to know the knowledge about if it possible doing it with javax.json or not as i tried to convert it using javax.json but i failed :(

Comment: Note that `javax.json` isn't part of the JDK, it is Java EE, not Java SE.

Comment: “First in map” makes no sense as a `HashMap` has no defined order. In other words, you can’t expect the JSON output to be in a particular order either. Just saying. Besides that, if your strings do not contain special characters, you can simply use ordinary `String` processing here: `String json = map.entrySet().stream()  .map(e -> "'"+e.getKey()+"': "+(e.getValue().isEmpty()? "[]": e.getValue().stream() .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "['", "']"))))  .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n  ", "{\n  ", "\n}"));`

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the following

```
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("First in list");
        list.add("Second in list");

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("First in secondlist");
        list1.add("Second in secondlist");

        map.put("First in map", list);
        map.put("Second in map", list1);

        final JsonArrayBuilder outerJsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        map.forEach((key, innerList) -> {

            JsonArrayBuilder innerJsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
            innerList.forEach(item -> innerJsonArray.add(item));

            outerJsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add(key, innerJsonArray));

        });

        JsonArray usersJson = outerJsonArray.build();
        System.out.println(usersJson.toString());
```

And the resulting JSON array is (missing the insertion order)

```
[
  {
    "Second in map": [
      "First in secondlist",
      "Second in secondlist"
    ]
  },
  {
    "First in map": [
      "First in list",
      "Second in list"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: That's a correct answer and actually i tried it before, so thank you for your time to comment this answer, anyway i was seeking for answer which read the map direct not loop on it and create the json by what ever way, for example just to make it simple to get my point something like Json.read(map) (this is not correct code of course, but i am just trying to reach you my point), thanks again :)